# Grails dependency with optaplanner and drools

Tags: grails, drools, optaplanner

I am using Grails with optaplanner 6.0.1.Final and drools jars (version 5.4.0) but getting some error while running the code. StackTrace is as follows :

```
 ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ClassNotFoundException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Volcare-BRMS/API/eventCreationDatePrePlanning
org.drools.core.event.AbstractEventSupport. Stacktrace follows:
Message: org.drools.core.event.AbstractEventSupport
    Line | Method
->>  366 | run                          in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run                          in     ''
|    354 | findClass . . . . . . . . .  in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass                    in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    800 | defineClass . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    142 | defineClass                  in java.security.SecureClassLoader
|    449 | defineClass . . . . . . . .  in java.net.URLClassLoader
|     71 | access$100                   in     ''
|    361 | run . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
|    355 | run                          in     ''
|    354 | findClass . . . . . . . . .  in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass                    in java.lang.ClassLoader
|     48 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . . in org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver
|    129 | buildSolver                  in org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig
|    101 | buildSolver . . . . . . . .  in org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.XmlSolverFactory
|     13 | createSolver                 in com.volcare.brms.CustomSolverFactory
|     74 | eventCreationDatePrePlanning in volcare.brms.api.APIController
|    200 | doFilter                     in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker                    in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                          in java.lang.Thread
```

I have also included all JAR files in classpath.

Comment: What Grails version do you use? Can you show us what dependencies you have declared in `BuildConfig.groovy`? Can you show us the dependency list?

Comment: compile 'org.drools:drools-api:5.1.1'
  compile 'org.drools:drools-jsr94:6.0.1.Final'
  compile 'org.drools:drools-compiler:5.4.0.Final'
  compile 'org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:6.0.1.Final'
  compile 'org.optaplanner:optaplanner-benchmark:6.0.1.Final'
  compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3'
  compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-lgpl:0.9.5'
  compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1.12'
  compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.1.12'

Comment: Can you run `grails dependency-report` and add the output to your question please?

Comment: Why do you use a different drools version than optaplanner? This most likely causes the problem

Answer (score 1):

The class `org.drools.core.event.AbstractEventSupport` seems to be part of the `drools-core` module. Optaplanner provides the correct Drools version so you DO NOT need to specify any Drools module in your `BuildConfig.groovy`.

```
compile 'org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:6.0.1.Final' 
compile 'org.optaplanner:optaplanner-benchmark:6.0.1.Final'
```

Comment: But i need to use org.drools:drools-core:6.0.1 as Optaplanner jar using it.

Comment: In this case make sure you include only 6.0.1 drools modules. Instead of `org.drools:drools-api:5.1.1` use `org.drools:drools-api:6.0.1.Final`...

Comment: Using this configuration : compile 'org.drools:drools-core:6.0.1.Final'
  compile 'org.drools:drools-compiler:6.0.1.Final'
  compile 'org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:6.0.1.Final'
  compile 'org.optaplanner:optaplanner-benchmark:6.0.1.Final'
  compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3'
  compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-lgpl:0.9.5'
  compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.1.12'
  compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.1.12' and getting this error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate service for Class 'org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService'

Comment: Getting these errors :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate service for Class 'org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService'
 at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl.get(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:161)
 at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.loadServiceFactory(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:131)
 at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.getKnowledgeBuilderServiceFactory(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:125)
 at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:47)

Comment: have look at my answer update. why do you define Drools dependencies anyway? Optaplanner provides these transitive dependencies.

Comment: If i am not defining the drools dependencies then my drools code is not working while Optaplanner code works fine.

Comment: So this means your Drools code is not compatible to Drools 6.0.1. You will need to upgrade your Drools code to Drools 6.0.1.Final. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I also find the same trying to solve the problem using ref https://github.com/profversaggi/mydrools_6.0_examples/blob/master